# Make library imports in tests compatible with two different packages that contain the library

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-unittest

I have a pretty weird scenario and goal. I need to make exact same tests work without any changes against a library that might be imported from two different packages.

There is a GIT repo with a big python package `big_sdk` and inside it there is a small library `big_sdk.small_lib`.

I'm extracting the `small_lib` library into a separate GIT repo and separate package `small_package.small_lib`.

The code will be living in both places for some time, so I want the code to be exactly the same in both places. (This allows significantly easier GIT workflow without any history merging problems.)

There is no problem with the small_lib library itself - it only uses relative imports inside, so the exact same code can live and work in a different package and repo.

The problem is with tests. The tests live in `big_sdk/tests/small_lib_tests` and use absolute imports:

```
from big_sdk import small_lib
from big_sdk.small_lib import some_module
from big_sdk.small_lib import some_func
```

When extracting the test code to the small repo, this has to be changed to

```
from small_package import small_lib
from small_package.small_lib import some_module
from small_package.small_lib import some_func
```

This is problematic due to breaking GIT history.

I want to find a different way.

Requirements:

- The goal is to make all code in `big_sdk/tests/small_lib_tests/` and `small_package/tests/` directories exactly the same. (There might be different files outside of those dirs though).
- The code in `big_sdk/*` should not mention `small_package`. This rules out a simple `try/except` approach with multiple import sources.

I have tried to switch the tests to import from a separate module `small_library.py` that imports `big_sdk.small_lib` in one repo and `small_package.small_lib` in another repo. It did not work for deeper imports like `from big_sdk.small_lib import some_module`. I then tried to use hacks that modified `sys.modules['component_library'] = big_sdk.small_lib`, and it partially worked, but required "registering" all sub-modules (`sys.modules['component_library.*']`) which was not easy and too hacky.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll just make the `small_lib` dir and the `small_lib_tests` dir siblings.

Before:

```
big_sdk/small_lib/*
tests/small_lib_tests/*
```

after:

```
big_sdk/small_lib/*
big_sdk/small_lib_tests/*
```

This looks somewhat ugly, but it allows relative imports from the test code.

```
from .. import small_lib
from ..small_lib import some_module
from ..small_lib import some_func
```

This way `big_sdk` and `small_package` are never mentioned in the code.